# How to detect when all directives have loaded?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a spinoff of another question ([Angular: running function in controller when all directives are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748657/angular-running-function-in-controller-when-all-directives-are-loaded)) as this one is general.

How can I detect when all angular directives on a page have loaded?

**EDIT:**

The only way I found so far is by setting up a directive at the highest level which triggers a scope function during it's link function. This works as angular compiles all directives on a page from outer to inner and calls link functions from inner to outer.

Downside: This no longer works if any of the inner directives uses a templateUrl as this will happen asynchronous. This will lead to the outer directives link function running before the inner directives link function. Additionally you'll have to add a directive to all views/includes.

**EDIT2:**

I found a great answer to a similar question which describes the problem above. And in the comments j_walker_dev mentions the following:

```
The way i got around this was to use template, like mentioned. 
But to inject $templateCache and do template: $templateCache.get('url.tpl.html').
```

SO question: [How to execute parent directive before child directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081140/how-to-execute-parent-directive-before-child-directive)

At least with this once can continue using templateUrls as it avoids the asynchronous behavior of template loading in directives.

Comment: do you mean in the index.html?

Comment: On any html side where you include directives. This could also be inside ng-view or ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

this is how protractor synchronize  :

```
functions.waitForAngular = function(rootSelector, callback) {
  var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);
  try {
    if (angular.getTestability) {
      angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
    } else {
      angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').
          notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    callback(e);
  }
};
```

Knowing that directives in cache will execute synchronously and one that needs to load template from server will execute before the $browser notify, This is how I would do it (if waiting for ajax requests others than for templates is not an issue)

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll have to take a look. The downside of this though seems to be that this is an internal API and should therefore not be used directly?

Comment: the getTestability 'might' be an internal API (this would mean that protractor in an internal angular project, which is not really the case). The 'notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests' is actually public on the browser service and can be used freely