# Load Data from Service in Angular Directive using Parameter from Directive Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I have the following code for an angular directive:

```
directive('searchTerms', ['$http', function ($http) {
            return {
                scope: { model: "=ngModel", metaDataUrl: "@metaData" },
                templateUrl: 'infohelper/SearchTermsTemplate',
                link: function ($scope) {...}
                controller: function ($scope) {...}
            }
}
```

For each use of the directive, a different URL is passed to the `$scope` variable `metaDataUrl`. Based on that different metadata should be loaded through an the `$http` service. And my question is: how do I make sure the metadata is loaded before the `link` function? Is there something similar to the `resolve` option in the `$routeProvider` service that one can use for directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` returns a promise, so you could manage the response asyncronously once it is ready inside your link function.

If not, you could declare a watcher inside your link function.

Take a look at this post: [Angular: running function in controller when all directives are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748657/angular-running-function-in-controller-when-all-directives-are-loaded)

It is a little bit different to your case but should help you.

Also you should read this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2095

Comment: No, that is not the right way to do it. I want to avoid just that – unnecessary digest cycles. I was wondering why isn't there a way to wait for a promise synchronously.

Comment: obviously it is not a nice way, but is a workaround. Synchronous programming is not recommended for the web, you cannot pause everything just for waiting for an http call.

Comment: Basically you are asking for something that does not exist, so you should find a workaround to cover your needs.